# Change Table Cell Colours From Database

Tags: php, html, css

Here's what I was doing (as part of a PHP echo):

```
<td bgcolor={$row['AwayB']}><font color={$row['AwayF']}>{$row['AwayTeam']}</font></td>
```

Then I found some CSS to alternate table row background colours:

```
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background: #666;
}
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td {
  background:#333;
}
```

But then the background colour was the same the whole way across the row, instead of changing for the two table cells it should change for (the second is almost identical to the first, just with 'home' instead of 'away'). And apparently I should be using CSS instead of the font tag anyway.

So I knocked together this in the stylesheet to test:

```
table.sortable tbody tr td.awayTeam {
    background-color:#900;
}
```

And removed the bgcolor code from the td tag and replaced it with class='awayTeam'. And it worked. And I found something on CSS-Tricks about using variables with CSS, and tried that, with this at the top of the CSS:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    $bgcolor = "#900";
?>
```

And then this as the style:

```
table.sortable tbody tr td.awayTeam {
    background-color:<?php echo $bgcolor; ?>;
}
```

Still worked. So I replaced $bgcolor with $row['AwayB'], and "{$row['AwayB']}", and ($row['AwayB'])...and all three just returned

```
table.sortable tbody tr td.awayTeam {
    background-color:;
}
```

Is there a way I can make this work?

EDITED TO ADD: Moving the CSS code into the while loop used to generate the table overrides the zebra striping and uses the team colour of the last team in the table for all teams. Overriding the zebra striping isn't a huge deal--the team colours provide enough differentiation--but obviously the colours need to work.

I need to keep the zebra striping in the table class, because I need that class for sorting and there are other, non-sports tables that need the background differentiation.

Comment: Did you externalise your CSS, then that is the reason. Your server will not evaluate  PHP inside a static CSS file. If it is no static, you will have to execute the DB call inside the new CSS php

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: {$row['AwayB']} has to come from somewhere no? And I guess your templating is not replacing the code in your new css.php

Comment: $row['AwayB'] is part of the result from a MySQL query. What do you mean by 'templating'?

Comment: If the query is not in the same file as the CSS then it is not available when you do the echo... Did you try `background-color: {$row["AwayB"]}` ?

Comment: Even if I put the CSS in the while loop that creates the table, it just uses the last colour value for all the cells of that class, and it's also overridden the alternating row background colours.

Comment: Sounds to me you want your cake and eat it too. If you have two colours one for away and one for home how will you use zebra striping?

Comment: There are other columns, but if I lose the zebra striping here it's not a huge deal (the same table class is used for other tables with no background colouring). But it's only using the last team's colour, so it's still not working.